# React-native fails to build for ios because command codesign failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, code-signing, yarnpkg

I recently updated my mac and all of a sudden I can't compile the application I've been working on in react-native.  The error it gives is `Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code`.

When it begins running this command, it says the Signing Identity is "-", even though that I have my signing correctly set in XCode.

It also says, `ios/build/Build/Products?Debug-iphonesimulator/project.app: resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed`.

This also results in a `No bundle URL present." in the iOS simulator.

If it helps, I am using yarn ios to compile.

I have tried solutions previously written for other code signing issues, none of which are related to react-native.  None of these solutions have worked.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding your project? I had a similar problem recently, and what worked for me is deleting everything from YOUR_PROJECT/ios/build/ and running react-native run-ios command again.